# Attachments not getting accessed or displayed in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, file, attachment, file-not-found

I have inserted an image here in this post (http://seminartopics.info/uncategorized/test/) and linked it to the same for download or view.
Link is http://seminartopics.info/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/paypal.gif
But it is not displayed in the post and also get 'Not Found' error if go to direct link.
Same problem with every files I have uploaded in this website.
This problem starts after I moved my website from some other host to current one

Comment: it is strange that I did not get a single reply to my question in stackoverflow users. May be because this was a silly question. One of my friend fixed it for me. It was due to file permission settings in my .htaccess file

Comment: There is a Stack exclusively for [WordPress](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/). Please, add the solution as an Answer, so this Question don't hang on the "Unanswered" category...

Answer (score 0):

It was due to file permission settings in my .htaccess file. One of my friend corrected it for me.